# App interface language?

Tags: system, language-support

Since i installed ubuntu 14.04 x64 , some programs are partially with chinese or japanese characters. I`ve updated system language , but it still not correct.My system is in portuguese Brasil, many apps are in english and its not a problem for me , but in japanese or chinese no way i could understand. I appreciate some help . Easystroke is the worst case , interface is completely in oriental characters.

```
**locale:**

LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=pt_BR:ja:en
LC_CTYPE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

**cat ~/.pam_environment**

LANGUAGE=pt_BR:ja:en
LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pt_BR.UTF-8
PAPERSIZE=a4


**cat /etc/default/locale**

LANG="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="pt_BR:ja:en"
LC_NUMERIC="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pt_BR.UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [Language Support](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-language.html) to control the display language.

Comment: I already did it before and applied to all system but still the same .

Comment: @EliasAlves: Please edit your question, and add the output from these commands: 1. `locale` 2. `cat ~/.pam_environment` 3. `cat /etc/default/locale`

Comment: Done . Outputs ok

Comment: @EliasAlves: The output explains your problem. The language priority list in the LANGUAGE variable has "ja" as the second language code. You should open Language Support and drag Japanese downwards. You may also want to click the "Help" button on the Language Support window for an explanation how it works.

Comment: It was already done before . I installed japanese language 2 days ago trying to solve this problem . Remember that system is partially affected: see some pictures: https://www.flickr.com/photos/127308574@N07/

Comment: @EliasAlves: It was apparently not done before. Please do as I suggested, and you won't see Japanese on the screen any longer.

Comment: The regular way it is not working. As you can see here (https://www.flickr.com/photos/127308574@N07/15065606143/), japanese is in the end , but if use locale it display japanese as second choice:

Comment: I think i should say that once in a while i install new versions of ubuntu but keep same home folder , maybe some configuration has been kept there.

Comment: @EliasAlves: I was talking about _Language Support_ (Suporte a idiomas), not _Text Entry_.

Comment: @ Gunnar Hjalmarsson :sorry about my mistake , i forgot that is possible move things there. Well, after do that it is working how it was supposed to , but i put english as first language , at least now i can understand what is written. Tomorrow i gonna get back to portuguese to see if it works . Another thing , even after uninstall japanese language it is still in panel choices in text entry. thank you

Comment: @EliasAlves: The options in Text Entry are about input language, while your concern was the display language. But you can delete Japanese in Text Entry, if you want, by clicking the minus sign.

Comment: @ Gunnar Hjalmarsson :You are right again . Appreciate